# How can I access the Auction House from out of game?

Tags: diablo-iii

I would like to keep tabs on my auctions during the day time while I'm away from the game.

Is it possible to access the Auction House in Diablo 3 from the Battle.net website?  If so, how?

Comment: Speculation about future content is non-constructive, as per our [FAQ].

Comment: I've removed the speculation part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there currently exists no way to access the AH outside of Diablo 3.

From Battle.net Support Documents:

> **Will there be a mobile or Web-based auction house?**
>
> We're always on the lookout for opportunities to enhance the game
>   experience and keep our community connected to our games through the
>   Web or mobile devices. However, we do not have any plans to share
>   along those lines at this time

http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-functionality#q21

Comment: With all of the people asking about an auction house API, I don't understand why Blizzard doesn't just provide a reason why to put the question to rest. Answers like "No", or "we do not have any plans to share along those lines at this time" are all a bunch of bs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [FAQ](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-general-information;jsessionid=A3C3D20D051C83824FDA37256335C171.blade32_08_bnet-support#q4) the only way to access the auction house is from the main menu inside the game.

> **Where do I access the auction house?**
>
> You can access the auction house from the campaign screen, prior to entering a game, by
> selecting the Auction House button from the left-side menu. If you are in the middle of playing a game, you will first need to leave the game and return to the main campaign screen in order to access the auction house.