# Is there an App for the Diablo 3 Auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I access the Auction House from out of game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67344/how-can-i-access-the-auction-house-from-out-of-game)

I know Blizzard made an app for World of Warcrafts auction house, but have they done this for Diablo 3 as well?  I checked my Iphone to no such luck, but since I don't have a Droid or Ipad, I wasn't sure if it was released for one of those platforms.  If the app does exist is it free, have a 1 time payment, or monthly recurring?  Really hoping there's an app for this somewhere or even an online auction house, but I haven't been able to find any online or on their site.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Appears so to me, unfortunately when I searched the site and made the thread, I didn't see that page at all :(

Comment: No big deal, duplicate questions get created all the time, it isn't counted against you at all.

Comment: Indeed, Duplicates are actually a good thing, as they help people find the original question using a variety of different search terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my knowledge there is no app and nothing like this has been announced yet. I guess Blizzard will check the success of D3 over the next month until they release such an application.

Comment: Just seems that it would be the logical thing for them to do, since it's out for WOW, and you'd think they would want to implement it before the Real Money Auction House goes up.  I mean, you'd think it would just increase their profits from it.

Comment: I guess especially for the RMAH they *may* release an application, but I don't know. The mentioned WoW-AH-app isn't available in the google play store (or it's not developed by Blizzard itself). By the way: You can check the google store without an android smartphone. Just go to www.play.google.com and start searching :]

Comment: They have not created an API for the Diablo 3 auction house thus there is no Diablo 3 Auction House mobile application.  It took 5+ years for the Auction House to have an API that could be viewed outside of the game ( i.e. the browser ).